# Gradle task bootrepackage hanging

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My gradle build is hanging at the bootRepackage task.
My application uses Gradle 2.14 + Spring Boot + Java

Gradle plugin is

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE")
```

Below is what I see in gradle logs. The execution is stuck up on the bootRepackage task with no errors:

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:findMainClass
:startScripts
:distTar
:distZip
> Building 81% > :bootRepackage
```

Gradle command executed:

```
gradle clean assemble
```

I added debug option but it didn't give me any additional information.
Please let me know any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing below snippet from my build.gradle file. I do not know why it was causing the issue but it solved the problem.
Please note that this issue comes only on local(Windows machine).

It will be great if any gradle expert can help explain why below snippet would cause the issue. Using gradle 2.14+spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE

```
from {

    configurations.runtime.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }

    configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}
```